# Why doesn't Java's .addShutdownHook work for Ctrl-C on BeagleBone Black? Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, ubuntu, clojure, beagleboneblack, shutdown-hook

## Problem

I have run the following Clojure code on both my Ubuntu development machine and the BeagleBone Black, and can confirm that it works on the former but not the latter.

```
(defn setup-shutdown-hook!                           
  [f]                                                  
  (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. f))) 

(setup-shutdown-hook!
  (fn []
    (println "I am no more")))

(defn -main []
  (doseq [i (range)]
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (println "Staying alive")))
```

On the BBB, the shutdown hook *does* work appropriately in the case of "natural" shutdowns, but not on Ctrl-C. On the Ubuntu machine, it seems to always work.

Is there some explanation for this different behavior? Java versions? System level differences? Is there a workaround for getting the desired behavior?

### System details

Ubuntu:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Beaglebone (running Angstrom; connected via SSH):

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
> uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13 #1 SMP Wed Sep 4 09:09:32 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**P.S.** For those of you familiar with Java but not Clojure, the Clojure code above just hooks into the Java methods through it's interop. Hopefully you can test the trans

Comment: Missing information: what distribution (including version) are you running on your bbb? How are you connecting to it in order to run your program?

Comment: Added above; thanks for the question. I'm connected via SSH, and running via leiningen.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear... there's no mystery here. I was lazy, cheated a bit, and ran on my Ubuntu machine with `lein exec` instead of `lein run` (as I did on the BBB) ._. Apparently, things seem to behave differently this way...

More to the point of how to get the desired behavior, `lein trampoline run -m <ns>` does the trick. The problem appears to be that since using `lein run` effectively runs your application within a nested JVM, the leiningen process catches the Ctrl-C instead of your application code. Using `lein trampoline` detaches the application code JVM such that it catches the Ctrl-C, and runs the shutdown code as desired.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855559/shutdown-hook-doesnt-fire-when-running-with-lein-run?rq=1) for showing me the light, and Stack overflow for it's wonderful "Related" questions.